# Taking $G$-invariants over a short exact sequence of $G$-modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules, group-homomorphism, exact-sequence

Let $G$ be a finite group and
$$
 0 \to P \stackrel{\phi}{\to} M \stackrel{\psi}{\to} N \to 0
$$
be an exact sequence of $G$-modules. In Appendix B of Silverman's *Arithmetic of Elliptic Curves*, it is said that taking the $G$-invariants gives an exact sequence
$$
 0 \to P^G \stackrel{\phi}{\to} M^G \stackrel{\psi}{\to} N^G
$$
but $\psi: M^G \to N^G$ does not necessarily have to be surjective.

Could you give me an example for such a case? I would like to understand this better but find these definitions about $G$-modules too abstract to begin with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

Look at the sequence

$$
0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2 \to 0
$$

as $\mathbb{Z}/2$-modules. Here the action on each module is by $x \mapsto -x$ (note this makes the action on $\mathbb{Z}/2$ trivial). Notice this means the action commutes with each of the module homs as well, so this really is a sequence of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-modules.

Now take $\mathbb{Z}/2$ invariants. Do you see what you get in each case? I'll include the answer under the fold, but you should really try to compute it yourself first!

> The only element of $\mathbb{Z}$ that gets fixed is $0$, but the whole of $\mathbb{Z}/2$ is fixed. So the sequence becomes
>  $$ 0 \to 0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2 $$
>  and surjectivity fails.

As an aside, one can show the $G$-invariant functor is naturally isomorphic to the functor $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z}, -)$. This might give some intuition for why this functor is *left* exact, but not exact in general. In fact, just like we can measure the failure of exactness of $\text{Hom}$ by looking at cohomology, there is a notion of [group cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_cohomology#Long_exact_sequence_of_cohomology) which measures the failure of exactness for this functor.

---

I hope this helps ^_^